# Compare UIButton current image with a image

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, xcode6

I'm trying to check if the image is the correct image in the UIButton. I have test this code were I know is the same image but doesn't work.

```
UIButton *myButton = sender;

if ([myButton.currentImage isEqual:
         [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_ImageBox_disabled.png"]])
{
    NSLog("is the same image");
}
```

Any of you know why this doesn't work or why when I compare the same image is not working?

Comment: Are the images guaranteed to have the same name or are you looking for a visual comparison?

Comment: I'm testing the code and they have the same image

Comment: I have a feeling that `isEqual` for images simply checks whether the two pointers are equal, and nothing guarantees that `imageNamed` will return the same object given the same name. It may, but doesn't have to. Try printing the pointers with `NSLog(@"%p",myButton.currentImage)`.

Comment: Have you tired googling "How to compare images iOS"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The default implementation just compares pointers.

```
UIButton *myButton = sender;

NSData *data1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myButton.currentImage);
NSData *data2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_ImageBox_disabled.png""]);

if ([data1 isEqual:data2])
{
    NSLog(@"is the same image");
}else{    
    NSLog(@"is not the same image");
}
```